# Detect which view controller I am currently dragging Table cell over

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collision-detection, drag

I long-press on a TableViewController's cell and drag the cell around my app. How can I detect that I am dragging over another TableViewController in the same app? If I drop the cell in the other TableViewController, I can handle that. But how can I detect that the cell from TableA has entered and being dragged around inside TableB without releasing my finger?

Similar questions about this seem to be about detecting collision with subviews of a given view, not another/different view.  Example: [iOS - Drag and drop collision detection How to detect when your selected item drags over another subview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947219/ios-drag-and-drop-collision-detection-how-to-detect-when-your-selected-item-dr)

Comment: Quick searching turns up this tutorial that looks like it explains exactly how to do what you're asking: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-drag-and-drop-to-your-app

Comment: I actually studied and implemented that particular mini project on the hackingwithswift website, and it is from doing that mini project that I raised the question which I did. My question is not about dragging a table cell and then dropping it into another table. My question is about how any view, such as table view B, can detect that a table cell being dragged from table view A has entered and dragged around within it _without_ releasing my finger, i.e. _before_ the table cell is dropped.

Comment: I haven't given it a try, but this should have all the info you need to do that: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_custom_view

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing `dropSessionDidEnter` ... and you probably also want to implement `dropSessionDidExit`.

We'll start with the tutorial you already studied at https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-drag-and-drop-to-your-app ... (slightly modified):

```
import MobileCoreServices

class DragDropViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,
                              UITableViewDragDelegate, UITableViewDropDelegate {
    
    var leftTableView = UITableView()
    var rightTableView = UITableView()
    
    var leftItems: [String] = []
    var rightItems: [String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        leftItems = (1...20).map { "Left Row \($0)" }
        rightItems = (1...20).map { "Right Row \($0)" }

        leftTableView.dataSource = self
        rightTableView.dataSource = self
        
        leftTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: 150, height: 400)
        rightTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 180, y: 40, width: 150, height: 400)
        
        leftTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        rightTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        
        view.addSubview(leftTableView)
        view.addSubview(rightTableView)
        
        leftTableView.dragDelegate = self
        leftTableView.dropDelegate = self
        rightTableView.dragDelegate = self
        rightTableView.dropDelegate = self
        
        leftTableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
        rightTableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == leftTableView {
            return leftItems.count
        } else {
            return rightItems.count
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        
        if tableView == leftTableView {
            cell.textLabel?.text = leftItems[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = rightItems[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let string = tableView == leftTableView ? leftItems[indexPath.row] : rightItems[indexPath.row]
        guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8) else { return [] }
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: data as NSData, typeIdentifier: kUTTypePlainText as String)
        
        return [UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)]
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
        let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
        
        if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
            destinationIndexPath = indexPath
        } else {
            let section = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
            let row = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
            destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        }
        
        // attempt to load strings from the drop coordinator
        coordinator.session.loadObjects(ofClass: NSString.self) { items in
            // convert the item provider array to a string array or bail out
            guard let strings = items as? [String] else { return }
            
            // create an empty array to track rows we've copied
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            
            // loop over all the strings we received
            for (index, string) in strings.enumerated() {
                // create an index path for this new row, moving it down depending on how many we've already inserted
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: destinationIndexPath.row + index, section: destinationIndexPath.section)
                
                // insert the copy into the correct array
                if tableView == self.leftTableView {
                    self.leftItems.insert(string, at: indexPath.row)
                } else {
                    self.rightItems.insert(string, at: indexPath.row)
                }
                
                // keep track of this new row
                indexPaths.append(indexPath)
            }
            
            // insert them all into the table view at once
            tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
        }
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {
        var dropProposal = UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
        
        // Accept only one drag item.
        guard session.items.count == 1 else { return dropProposal }
        
        // The .move drag operation is available only for dragging within this app and while in edit mode.
        if tableView.hasActiveDrag {
            if tableView.isEditing {
                dropProposal = UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
            }
        } else {
            // Drag is coming from outside the app.
            dropProposal = UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
        
        return dropProposal
    }
    
}
```

If you run that, you should have "left" and "right" table views, and you should be able to drag from the left table and drop into the right table.

If your goal is to do something when the drag **enters** the right table, implement these functions:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidEnter session: UIDropSession) {
        if tableView == rightTableView {
            tableView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidExit session: UIDropSession) {
        tableView.layer.borderWidth = 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidEnd session: UIDropSession) {
        rightTableView.layer.borderWidth = 0
    }
```

When the drop `session` enters the right table view, we'll set its border width to 2, and set it back to 0 when the `session` exits the right table view.

We've also implemented `dropSessionDidEnd` so we can reset the border to 0 when the drop is completed. We *could* do that in `performDropWith`, but I've done it this way for clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not at my iMac now but it looks like that's what I need!

Comment: Turns out that `dropSessionDidUpdate` (which wasn't included in that HackingWithSwift mini-project) was enough for me to do what I wanted. Thanks again.